# Is there any way to hide logging of variables in a log file for wix bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I have created a wix bootstrapper application with registry search variables in Bundle.wxs file. After installing the setup if I go through the log file I can see logging of registry search variables with the values. In my scenario values should not be visible  in the log file.Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You just mark your variable as Hidden. For example:
`<Variable Name="Foo" Hidden="yes"/>`